# ¿Cómo encontrar un Objeto dentro de un arreglo, dada una Key y un valor? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un arreglo lleno de objetos cuyos atributos son desconocidos, me dan una key (el nombre de esta misma) y un valor para esta key. ¿Como puedo encontrar el objeto haciendo uso de dicha key?.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a SO en español! Léete [ask] y haz el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona este sitio. Debes mostrar lo que intentaste, los errores que te aparecen, un [example], para que consideremos la pregunta válida y podamos ayudarte. Tal como está redactada podria [cerrarse](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) porque [no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/263200) y por [pedirnos realizar tus tareas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4320/263200). Aquí **no hacemos código a medida** (o no deberiamos @StialManstike)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

puedes usar tanto filter() como find() dependiendo de lo que quieras obtener, una lista de coincidencias o el primer objeto,

```
[].filter(element => element["tu_key"] ==  tu_value);
// retorna []
[].find(element => element["tu_key"] ==  tu_value);
// retorna {}
```