# ¿Como encuentro el valor que mas se repite en un array? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Dado un array con 'x' cantidad de valores, necesito obtener el que mas se repite de todos ellos. Ojo, no la cantidad de veces que se repite, sino el valor en si.

Comment: [Repetimos comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/513253/263200) ¡Bienvenido a SO en español! Léete [ask] y haz el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona este sitio. Debes mostrar lo que intentaste, los errores que te aparecen, un [example], para que consideremos la pregunta válida y podamos ayudarte. Tal como está redactada podria cerrarse porque [no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/263200) y por [pedirnos realizar tus tareas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4320/263200). Aquí no hacemos código a medida (o no deberiamos)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

este codigo te devuelve el valor y la cantidad de veces que lo cuenta, espero y te sirva.

```
const array1 = [3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 3, 4, 5, 7, 3, 2, 6, 3, 6, 4, 7, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9, 3, 5];

const busqueda = (arreglo, callback) => {
    let variable = 0;
    let contador = 0;
    let cuenta = 0;
    arreglo.map(p => {
        cuenta = 0
        arreglo.map(x => {
            if (p == x) { cuenta++ }
        })
        if (cuenta > contador) {
            contador = cuenta;
            variable = p;
        }
    });
    callback(`valor mas repetido:${variable}, numero de veces contada: ${contador}`)

}

busqueda(array1, (respuesta) => {
    console.log(`respuesta: ${respuesta}`)
});
```

Comment: Hola Gabriel. Bienvenido al Sitio. Tu respuesta es correcta, sin embargo estás recibiendo votos negativos porque las respuestas a preguntas de baja calidad no son bienvenidas. La pregunta no sigue los lineamientos del sitio, entre ellos está demostrar investigación, proveer datos/código de ejemplo, entre otros.